# How to trigger a job success to a pipeline workflow before archiving artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-build-flow

I have the Jenkins pipeline which contains series of job (for testing using Selenium & Cucumber BDD). Every time we run the pipeline, even the functional test is passed (i called it test status) it takes time  for saving the artifacts then job is considered to be PASSED (this i called Job status). So let's say for a simple test that take only 1 minute to run , but saving the artifacts from Jenkins slave to Jenkins master take around the same time or more before it's considered to be passed. In regarding to the `fast feedback` to the team while running these jobs, it slows down the whole flow.

So, I wonder if there's way that i can modify or config for the post-build actions to send the test status to the pipeline right after running the test (but still saving the artifacts ? )

I just configured the `post-build` actions:

- Archive the artifacts - File to archive : `**`

My expectation, basically is, the test status (`passed/failed`) will be parsed right away to Pipeline build scripts, so that the pipeline script will 'acknowledge' it way faster.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding without upload completion, success or failure status can't be sent to the upstream job.